# How is the process of policy making for Islam.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I mean how a rule of this site is determined?

Can a moderators answer a meta question and then himself consider his own meta answer as a policy and rule of site and delete/close/put on hold main site questions or answers?

I do not know how is the process of making a rule?

Is it by asking a meta question and then the accepted answer be the rule? or the meta answer with the most vote will become the rule of site?

Does this site has any legislation system?

Can any meta post be used as a rule by mods to delete a post? or meta posts are only suggestions and what are declared in help center are rules that moderation actions can be done based on them?

I think currently rules of site are unclear and too broad and highly depends on personal interpretation of moderators (in fact one active moderator) from different meta posts.

Why a meta post is simply ignored by a mod and another meta post is used as a rule for deleting posts?

What makes value of meta posts more or less in using them as a rule?

Indeed I am not talking about Administrative policies of SE that are enforced to all SE sites. but I am talking about other policies that should be decided by Islam community itself.

Comment: interestingly relevant question on PSE: http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/320

Comment: @goldPseudo interesting! my answer to that questions would be: a mixture of democracy and dictatorship. because some rules are dictated to users and users can not vote for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can find similiar discussions that are asked on [Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-should-policy-decisions-be-finalized-and-codified-here) and [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/what-is-process-for-determining-consensus-on-policy) SE sites. Both of them have really good answer, one of them is from SE community manager. I will offer you my overview of those answer.

First of all, I would like to point out that, policy making process in SE sites in general are community driven and fluid processes. That means that as communities grows and evolves, policies can be added, substracted or modified as deemed necessary for community by the community.

While defining and refining the site policies, we are not completely free, as we should stick to Administrative policies of SE site and similiar rules on the Network. Therefore, policy's that adhere to general philisophy of Network are much likely to be established as islam.SE policies and policies that contradicts with how a Stack Exchange site work is most likely will not end up being a islam.SE policy.

If there are competing policies that are in accordance with the way that Stack Exchange works, than we should gauge how community feels about it. Meta answer on a related discussion can be used for this purpose. We can use most upvoted answers on meta questions as site policies. Of course, same issue might be opened for discussion later, and can be reviewed.

Here is an another discussion: [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/how-is-consensus-determined-on-meta-sites)