# Does Islam.SE has its own specific policy or not?

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-policy

I received a comment from one of moderators:

> You keep asking for some sort of Islam.SE-specific policy, but there
>   is no such thing. Check out meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/132874 if
>   you want a relevant meta discussion. [source](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/based-on-what-site-policy-and-by-what-decision-making-process-the-question#comment1984_1049)

It is amazing for me to hear this site has no specific policy.

I think it has contradiction with this meta post by user:

[Policy Discussions of Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/policy-discussions-of-islam-se)

And also with this post with the same user:

https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1036/67

Some of policies are enforces by SE Inc. Indeed I am not talking about them. I talk about others that Islam site community itself should decide about them.

There are two options:

1- Everything depend on moderators. they search and find some meta posts from all over the SE network and take action based on them and their own opinion and interpretation.

2- Islam site have a clear set of policies. not in form a jungle of meta QAs, but something like developed version of current help center that can be updated by time. in this case moderators can take moderation actions (like deleting of closing posts) only according to one of per-defined and clear Islam site policies.

Here are some similar discussions on other sites of SE network:

https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-should-policy-decisions-be-finalized-and-codified-here

https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/what-is-process-for-determining-consensus-on-policy

[How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/how-is-consensus-determined-on-meta-sites)

Please note this question does not mean deleting all help center and all past useful knowledge for managing this site. but means the part of policies that can not be used from past knowledge according to nature of Islam as a religion. perhaps 90% of site policy can be taken from past useful knowledge. but still 10% is needed to be made specifically for this site. I am talking about that 10%.

Comment: I think he meant that there is no site-specific policy regarding the particular issue that you bring up because it is unnecessary as a result of there being a wider SE policy.

Comment: Also, your dichotomy is a false one. There are SE policies *and* there are Islam.SE policies. Both are enforceable here.

Comment: Down voters please mention for reason. this question is simply asking for how this site works. what meta is made for it. http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta also please read here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/982/please-vote-based-on-quality

Comment: @Daniel SE policies are only advice for this site. as they are past useful knowledge. but they should be first checked to see if are applicable to Islam as a religion or not and then accepted by Islam.SE community and then enforced. please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins/124915#124915

Answer (score 6):

Sites generally create their own specific policies *when there's a clear need for it*.

Just because a policy originated elsewhere doesn't make it *wrong* for this site - after all, in many respects this site is quite similar to many other sites.

I've heard that some folks live their day-to-day lives based on rules originally written for people many thousands of miles away and many years ago... This is no different; people are people.

If you come upon a scenario where the existing rules clearly *cause harm* due to circumstances unique to this site, then *bring **that specific scenario** up for discussion* - otherwise, don't turn your nose up at useful knowledge just because it didn't originate here.

#### See also: [Individual community preferences vs. SE network policy: who wins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins/124915#124915)

Comment: I think deleting question asking for If Israel is enemy of Islam harms the purpose of this site which is knowing Islam. knowing enemies of Islam is part of knowing Islam. I brought it in meta but it was ignored.

Comment: Seems like you missed a chance to learn a valuable lesson about *this site...*

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about my question. I do not mean leave the useful knowledge. it is already being used in help center of this site. I mean Islam has lots of rules about politics which makes Islamic politics on-topic here. in this specific case Islam site has conflict with general rule of SE about politics. what is that lesson?

Comment: The lesson is that there is no conflict; you just disagree with some of your peers as to what is an appropriate topic here.

Comment: @Shog9, It's not like that! it seems that some mods here are acting on their own without caring about the community!!  I would so much want we graduate and have elections

Comment: You can discuss any specific action here on meta for as long as you need to. That should not preclude moderators or other users taking *action* on the main site however. If you disagree with popular opinion, then the onus is on you to change it - the folks here have no reason to let you stonewall when there's work to be done. I have very little sympathy for folks who can't make up their minds and instead spend their days getting in the way of everyone else.

Comment: @Bludream The moderators might seem like dictators to you, but I think that they are trying to get the community to act in a way that is more consistent with other more established SE sites. Only when that happens is it *possible* that this site can graduate.

Comment: Although, I somewhat disagree with the notion. But bring up [specific actions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15120116#15120116) and asking the reason to it is considered less engaging.